# Creating a new pandas column based on certain ifs and also involving row operations

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say i have a data frame of the below nature.
Please note the indexes are not serial.

```
    A    B
a   6.5  1
b   6.8  0
c   7    0
f   6    1
h   6.1  0
i   6.2  0
```

I want to create a new column C such that
if B is 1, then C = A
else C = A(b) - A(a) ....Here A(a) should be the one that has B=1 as its recent row.

Eg. In case of row c, the value of Column C should be 7-6.5.
Can you please assist to frame this logic.

Comment: Is possible first value of `B` is not `1` ?

Comment: Yes its possible

Comment: OK, so if first value is `0` in column `B` what is desired output for first 3 rows? I think in column `B` is only one `1` in `f` row.

Comment: If use my solution get `NaN`s for this rows.

Comment: Yes, NaNs fine if the df's first few rows are 0 for column B
Thanks a ton jezrael !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with `ffill` - forward filling `NaN`s:

```
m = df['B'] == 1
df['C'] = np.where(m, df['A'], df['A'] - df['A'].where(m).ffill())
```

Or:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].where(m, df['A'] - df['A'].where(m).ffill())

print (df)
     A  B    C
a  6.5  1  6.5
b  6.8  0  0.3
c  7.0  0  0.5
f  6.0  1  6.0
h  6.1  0  0.1
i  6.2  0  0.2
```

Detail:

```
print (df['A'].where(m).ffill())
a    6.5
b    6.5
c    6.5
f    6.0
h    6.0
i    6.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```